# How to get Firebase to shut up about "Error getting App Check token"?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-app-check, google-play-integrity-api

I'm developing a Flutter application and using Firebase and Google Cloud for much of my backend services. However my emulator logs are filled nonstop with spam like this:

```
W/LocalRequestInterceptor(11031): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed.
W/LocalRequestInterceptor(11031): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed.
```

I will not be shooting myself in the foot with App Check, since the Integrity API doesn't work on some of my devices. There are similar questions on Stackoverflow where users are trying to install App Check, but that is not my case.

How can I mute/suppress/get rid of these logs?

Comment: Do you call `FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate` in your code or do you get these logs without activating AppCheck?

Comment: No - I don't have `firebase_app_check` in my project and nothing in my code uses `FirebaseAppCheck.instance`

Answer (score 1):

Searching the code, the error comes from `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java` which is generated by `flutterEmbedding` in `AndroidManifest.xml`. I'm not sure why it included an entry for App Check, but deleting that file then running `flutter run` seemed to rebuild it without App Check.